# Al intentar crea un trigger after update en la BD, me retorna error SQL Error 1064

Tags: mysql

El código que estoy ejecutando es el siguiente:

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_update_posts AFTER UPDATE
    ON wp_posts 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
    IF NEW.post_type = 'hotel' OR 
    NEW.post_type = 'room_type' OR 
    NEW.post_type = 'tour' then
     UPDATE trigger_nuevo_post 
        SET actualizado = 1,
            fecha_actualizacion = NOW()
         WHERE post_id = NEW.ID;
    end if; 
END;
```

al ejecutarlo me retorna error

> SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
> the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near '' at line 12

He formateado el código de diferentes maneras y el error se mantiene. Alguna ayuda por favor?

Gracias

Comment: Qué versión de MySQL usas?

Answer (score 0):

Yo cambiaría el delimitador durante la definición del trigger, pues no es evidente para mysql si estás terminando la declaración del trigger o la de una instrucción en su interior.

Al decirle que vas a usar ahora otro delimitador (puede ser `$$` u otra cosa que elijas), el trigger completo se va a compilar correctamente, pues MySQL esperará a que introduzcas el nuevo delimitador de "fin de instrucción" para compilar el trigger.

Luego, puedes volver al `;` punto y coma tradicional.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER after_update_posts AFTER UPDATE
    ON wp_posts 
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF 
      NEW.post_type = 'hotel' OR 
      NEW.post_type = 'room_type' OR 
      NEW.post_type = 'tour' 
    THEN
      UPDATE trigger_nuevo_post 
      SET actualizado = 1, fecha_actualizacion = NOW()
      WHERE post_id = NEW.ID;
    END IF; 
END$$    

DELIMITER ;
```